# What's the meaning of "creep" (noun) in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

There's a sentence I don't understand. A girl is thinking about a man she likes:

> She would nestle herself against him for warmth, for comfort, and that small act would abate the **creep** of isolation that always threatened her.

I understand the general meaning, but what does "creep" mean exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*creep*

> slow steady movement, especially when imperceptible.

In this sentence the small act (of being with this person) stops the feeling of isolation that usually builds (slowly) inside her.